# Converting binary reading function from C# to C

Tags: c#, c, binary-data

I am honestly really confused on reading binary files in C.

My data is in a format like:

- int header
- Cell[][] cells, 8x8 matrix
- Each cell is just a short id and a sbyte z.

However, something is clearly messing up and none of the values are accurate.

```
  int i, j;
  Block block;

  // read 32 bits
  fread( &(block.header), sizeof( int ), 1, mapFile );

  // loop through to fill the 8x8 matrix
  for( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
  {
    for( j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
    {
      // read 16 bits
      fread( &(block.cells[i][j].tileId), sizeof( short ), 1, mapFile );
      // read 8 bits
      fread( &(block.cells[i][j].z), sizeof( char ), 1, mapFile );

      printf( "[%i][%i]: %x %i", i, j, block.cells[i][j].tileId, block.cells[i][j].z );
    }
  }
  printf( "header: %i", block.header );
```

Output of above shows a bunch of lines with `[n][n]: ffffa800 251`.

My C# version works fine though:

```
            Block block;
            block.header = reader.ReadInt32();
            block.cells = new Cell[8,8];
            for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
            {
                for ( int j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
                {
                    block.cells[i, j].tileId = reader.ReadInt16();
                    block.cells[i, j].z = reader.ReadSByte();
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
```

Output from that (correctly) shows `[n][n]: a8 -5`.

Comment: This might be a byte-order issue...?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness - Any time you read byte-by-byte (as you do in C), you can run into endian issues.  Can you give a short sample of which each bit of code prints (can be truncated to the first few lines, maybe one or two of the outer loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use more strictly defined types in C. For example, int32_t (stdint.h). It's possible that your `short` is 32-bit (or even your `int` is 16-bit), albeit unlikely.

It's probably also worthwhile to show us how the Block `struct` is defined.

For reference:

`SByte` = `int8_t`

`Int16` = `int16_t`

`Int32` = `int32_t`

Comment: Wow, changing them helped a bit. The cell's z value (signed byte) changed correctly to -5, but the tileId value (short) is still unchanged.

Comment: Try outputting the value as %hx rather than %x.

Comment: Try %d in lieu of %hx. Hopefully 168

Comment: The reason I mentioned that was because %x, by standard, is supposed to be displayed as `uint16_t` (`unsigned int16_t`) while %d is supposed to be `int16_t`. %hx was an old style way to do `short int` that I found after a quick search. [Here is the header for predefined printf constants](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scnx32).

Comment: The reason this is happening is the reason that Merlyn pointed out in combination with the size issues. When Java came out, they standardized their output to Big Endian, and .NET followed them with binary writers. Change the tile read to this: `int16_t tile; fread(&tile, sizeof(int16_t), 1, mapFile); blocks.cells[i][j].tileId = htons(tile);` You can find the htons method in netinet/in.h

Comment: I suspect that you will need to use `htonl` (same include) for the block.header value as well.

Comment: It seems that my .NET comment was mistaken (the Java one was not). However, the described issue is cured by correcting the endianness.

Comment: I think this should be ntoh* (network [big endian] to host) rather than hton (host to network [big endian]).

Answer (score 1):

This might very well have to do with the fact that a short is not always guaranteed to be two bytes. Maybe it is better to read the specified number of bytes and then convert it into the desired datatype? this also goes for int. By the way: fread returns the number of bytes read, so you are able to check if the desired number of bytes is actually read.

Regards, Perry

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be using C# to write the file (`BinaryWriter`) and C to read it back. Thus the file may have some unexpected value at the beginning (some header, length, a BOM whatever). Use a hex editor to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In C variables are initialized by default to an undefined state, so you cannot rely on their contents until you have explicitly initialized them. Remember to allocate all the memory that you will need and to zero out the contents (initializing them) before they are used.

For example: `memset(&block, '\0', sizeof block);`